# how to use python popen to print and also store communicate and return code?

Tags: python, printing, subprocess, popen

this is the function i am creating,  i have one argument that can tell to print real time or not since some of the process take like an hour.  and since i am subprocesing several at the same time, another argument to raise an error and stop everything, or just let the main script run.

but if i do print_real_time True, i loose the p.communicate()
i could store all the prints from the iter in a variable and return that, but how do i put in order the std out, and the stderr,  and get the return value to see if did fail or not?

```
def launch_subprocess_cmd(command_to_lunch, cwd=None, print_real_time=False,    raise_errors=True):
"""
for a given command line will lunch that as a subprocess
:param command_to_lunch: string
:param print_real_time: boolean
:param cwd: the folder path from where the command should be run.
:param raise_errors: boolean if the return code of the subprocess is different than 0 raise an error an stop all scripts.
                        else the main script will keep running and can access the third return value of this function and decide what to do with it.
:return: list com return the stdout and the stderr of the Popen subprocess.
"""
if cwd is None:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command_to_lunch, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
else:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command_to_lunch, cwd=cwd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

if print_real_time is True:
    for i in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print i

com = p.communicate()
if raise_errors is True:
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise ValueError("\n\nSubprocess fail: \n" + "Error captures: \n" + "stdout:\n" + com[0] + "\nstderr:\n" + com[1] + "\n")
# com[0] is std_out, com[1] is std_err and p.return code is if the subprocess was successful or not with a int number
return com[0], com[1], p.returncode
```

thanks guys =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to your problem is to store the stdout stream in a list when `print_real_time` is `True` and then use the content of the list to generate the stdout data string. If `print_real_time` is not `True`, then use the content from `com[0]` instead.

```
def launch_subprocess_cmd(cmd, cwd=None, print_real_time=False, raise_errors=True):
    """
    for a given command line will lunch that as a subprocess
    :param cmd: string
    :param print_real_time: boolean
    :param cwd: the folder path from where the command should be run.
    :param raise_errors: boolean if the return code of the subprocess is different
                         than 0 raise an error an stop all scripts else
                         the main script will keep running and can access the third
                         return value of this function and decide what to do with it.
    :return: list com return the stdout and the stderr of the Popen subprocess.
    """
    if cwd is None:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    else:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=cwd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    stdout_list = []
    if print_real_time is True:
        for i in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            stdout_list.append(i)
            print i

    com = p.communicate()
    stdout_data = "".join(stdout_list) if print_real_time is True else com[0]

    if raise_errors is True:
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise ValueError("\n\nSubprocess fail: \n" + "Error captures: \n" +
                             "stdout:\n" + stdout_data + "\nstderr:\n" +
                             com[1] + "\n")
    # stdout_data is stdout, com[1] is stderr and
    # p.return code is if the subprocess was successful or not with a int number
    return stdout_data, com[1], p.returncode
```

As a side note, I would also urge you to try to rewrite the program to **not** use `shell=True` in your `Popen` calls. It may require that you preprocess the input `cmd` into a list of base command and arguments, but it is generally considered a bad idea to use `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
launch_subprocess_cmd(command_to_lunch, cwd=None, print_real_time=False, raise_errors=True):
if cwd is None:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command_to_lunch, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
else:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command_to_lunch, cwd=cwd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

stdout_list = []
errout_list = []
if print_real_time is True:
    for i in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        stdout_list.append(i)
        print i
    for j in iter(p.stderr.readline, b''):
        errout_list.append(j)
        print j

com = p.communicate()
if print_real_time is True:
    stdout_data = "".join(stdout_list)
    std_err_data = "".join(errout_list)
else:
    stdout_data = com[0]
    std_err_data = com[1]

if raise_errors is True:
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise ValueError("\n\npopen fail:\n" + command_to_lunch + "\nError:\n" + "Error captures:\n" + "stdout:\n" + stdout_data + "\nstderr:\n" + std_err_data + "\n")
# com[0] is out, com[1] is errors and p.return code is if it fail or not
return stdout_data, std_err_data, p.returncode
```